# Regex not working for comma separated list of strings

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regex for following values:

```
Ha2:123hD,Ha2:123hD,Ha2:123hD - correct match - true
Ha2:123hD,Ha2:123hD,Ha2:123hD,  - comma on end - false
Ha2:123hD,Ha2:123hD,Ha2:123hD,,Ha2:123hD - double comma- false
,Ha2:123hD,Ha2:123hD,Ha2:123hD - comma at start- false
```

I am trying the following regex:

```
/(([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(\W)([a-zA-Z0-9]+))/
/(([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(\W)([a-zA-Z0-9]+,)*([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(\W)([a-zA-Z0-9])+$)/
```

But it is not working.

Comment: If you need to only match comma-separated alphanumerical strings, use `/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:,[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$/`

Answer (score 1):

You could put the comma at the start of the repeating group.

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+[:][a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:,[a-zA-Z0-9]+[:][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$/
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to check for these fix strings (As I have to guess from your question), this will work `^(Ha2:123hD,)*Ha2:123hD$`

And otherwise, you just can follow this expression and replace the `Ha2:123hD` with your wildcard expression.

Also check this website:
https://regex101.com/
It explains nicely how the single symbols of a regex work.

Answer (score 0):

To only match **comma-seaprated alphanumeric + `:` string lists** you may use

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9:]+(?:,[a-zA-Z0-9:]+)*$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/47q7GU/1)

**Explanation**:

- `^` - start of string anchor
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` - a character class matching 1 or more (due to `+` quantifier)
  ASCII letters or digits or `:`
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group....

  - `,`  - a comma
  - `[a-zA-Z0-9:]+` - a character class matching 1 or more (due to `+` quantifier)  ASCII letters or digits or `:`
- `)*` - .... 0 or more occurrences (due to the `*` quantifier)
- `$` - end of string.